# Resolve promise ethersJs

Tags: javascript

I have here this code but whenever a new pair is being detected i get back
[object promise]

```
function main(){
    console.log('Starting...')
   contractBsc.on('PairCreated', (token0, token1, pair) =>{
        var erc20COntract0 = new ethers.Contract(token0, erc20Abi, provider) 
        var erc20COntract1 = new ethers.Contract(token1, erc20Abi, provider)  
        let name0 =  erc20COntract0.name()
        var name1 =  erc20COntract1.name()
        var symbol0 = erc20COntract0.symbol()
        var symbol1 = erc20COntract1.symbol()    
        console.log(`Token0: ${name0}, Symbol: ${symbol0}\nToken1: ${name1}, Symbol: ${symbol1}`)
       // return name0,name1,symbol0,symbol1
    }) 
    
  
}
main()
```

How can I resolve the promise and than use the variables name1, name0 etc in my script

Answer (score 1):

Make the function `async` and add `await` where ever there is a promise.
I believe this is how your code should look

```
contractBsc.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pair) =>{
        var erc20COntract0 = await new ethers.Contract(token0, erc20Abi, provider) 
        var erc20COntract1 = await new ethers.Contract(token1, erc20Abi, provider)  
        let name0 =  await erc20COntract0.name()
        var name1 =  await erc20COntract1.name()
        var symbol0 = await erc20COntract0.symbol()
        var symbol1 = await erc20COntract1.symbol()    
        console.log(`Token0: ${name0}, Symbol: ${symbol0}\nToken1: ${name1}, Symbol: ${symbol1}`)
       // return name0,name1,symbol0,symbol1
    })
```

also you can optimize by using `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled` for concurrent requests.

Promise.all Example

```
 const [name0,name1,symbol0,symbol1] =  await
 Promise.all([erc20COntract0.name,erc20COntract1.name,erc20COntract0.symbol,erc20COntract1.symbol])
```

now name0 and name1 are fetched concurrently. However if either of these fail both of the request will fail. You will have to decide if you are ok for your case or you can use Promise.allsettled where few promise can fail while otthers pass.
Here is a an MDN exmaple for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [Promise.allsettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: its working dude, post a example of promise.all

Comment: added that example but use concurrent call only if any of those call doesn't depend on the other.